# Insert Node as parent

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I have XML column with content like this

```
<Root>
  <Element>
    <ToMove/>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <Envelope>
      <Good>SomeValue</Good>
    </Envelope>
  </Element>
 <Element>
    <ToMove/>
 </Element>
 <Element>
    <Envelope>
      <Good>SomeValue</Good>
    </Envelope>
  </Element>
</Root>
```

I want to add new node Envelope between Element and ToMove. (Element/Envelope/ToMove) using XQuery.

I tried adding Envelope/ToMove as sibling to ToMove but insert does not support adding multiple nodes. Adding Envelope alone and then adding ToMove in next statement does not seem possible since there are already Envelope nodes that should not get ToMove node.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Order and number of Element nodes are variable.

Comment: The proper XQuery solution (a modification of the identity function) can't be used in your enviroment: SQL Server doesn't implement a full standard complain XQuery engine with function declarations.

Comment: My original problem was that I was adding new node to multiple destination nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it for you. Comments in code describes what I do.

```
-- Setup test data two records with four elements in each
declare @Records table(ID int, Content xml)
insert into @Records values
(1, '<Root>
       <Element>
         <ToMove/>
       </Element>
       <Element>
         <Envelope>
           <Good>SomeValue 1</Good>
         </Envelope>
       </Element>
      <Element>
         <ToMove/>
      </Element>
      <Element>
         <Envelope>
           <Good>SomeValue 2</Good>
         </Envelope>
       </Element>
     </Root>'),
(2, '<Root>
       <Element>
         <ToMove/>
       </Element>
       <Element>
         <Envelope>
           <Good>SomeValue 3</Good>
         </Envelope>
       </Element>
      <Element>
         <ToMove/>
      </Element>
      <Element>
         <Envelope>
           <Good>SomeValue 4</Good>
         </Envelope>
       </Element>
     </Root>')

-- Split the elements, one row each to @T
declare @T table (ID int, Element xml)

insert into @T
select
  ID,
  r.query('.')
from @Records
  cross apply Content.nodes('Root/Element') as r(r)

-- Insert Envelop/ToMove where there exist a ToMove
update @T
set Element.modify('insert <Envelope><ToMove/></Envelope> into (Element[1])')
where Element.exist('Element/ToMove') = 1

-- Remove ToMove from Element node
update @T
set Element.modify('delete Element/ToMove')

-- Save changes back to @Records, recombine elements
update @Records
set Content = 
  (
    select (select T.Element) 
    from @T as T
    where T.ID = R.ID
    for xml path('Root')
  )
from @Records as R

--Result
select *
from @Records
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael, but your example won't work for me because I can have multiple Element nodes.

Comment: @Enes Please update your sample xml so it shows your actual situation.

Comment: @Enes I see that you have solved your question but just for the fun of it I updated my answer with a new version.

Comment: Sorry for not answering on this before, had few busy days. Even tough I used my solution, your looks much better and will mark your as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My original problem was that I was adding new node to multiple destination nodes. I managed to accomplish this task using two while loops. In first I iterate through all records that contain `Element/ToMove` node, then in each record i do loop through all instances of `Element/ToMove` node and add as sibling node `Envelope/ToMove`. And as last step I delete all instances of `Element/ToMove`.

I ended up with following code:

```
-- Create table that will temporarily hold matching records
CREATE TABLE #UpdatedRecords
(
    ExistingId int,
    NewContent xml,
    IsProcessed bit
)

INSERT INTO #UpdatedRecords
SELECT      Id,
            Content,
            0 -- At the beginning, records are not processed
FROM        Records
WHERE       Content.exist( '//Element/ToMove' ) = 1

DECLARE @HasMore bit
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Content xml
DECLARE @Position int   

SET     @HasMore = 1
WHILE   ( @HasMore = 1 )
    BEGIN
        -- Select next unprocessed record
        SELECT  @Id = ExistingId, @Content = NewContent
        FROM    #UpdatedRecords
        WHERE   IsProcessed = 0

        IF @Id IS NULL
            SET @HasMore = 0
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- Prepare new Content
                SET     @Position = 1
                WHILE   ( @Content.exist('(//Element/ToMove)[sql:variable("@Position")]') = 1 )
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Content.modify
                        ('
                            insert <Envelope><ToMove /></Envelope> after ((//Element/ToMove)[sql:variable("@Position")])[1]
                         ') 

                        SET @Position = @Position + 1   
                    END     

                -- Update Content and mark record as processed
                UPDATE  #UpdatedRecords
                SET     NewContent = @Content,
                        IsProcessed = 1
                WHERE   ExistingId = @Id
            END

        -- Reset Id
        SET @Id = NULL
    END

Update  #UpdatedRecords 
SET     NewContent.modify('delete //Element/ToMove')

-- Update original records
UPDATE  Records
SET     Contents = NewContents
FROM    #UpdatedRecords
WHERE   Id = ExistingId
```